# Highlight Multiple Syntax at Once in Sublime Text 2?

Tags: php, css, sublimetext

I have a CSS file that is about half CSS and half PHP. Is there a way to apply syntax highlighting to both at once?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer would be don't use extensive PHP in CSS. Have your processing done in the file that includes the css file, or just use str_replace(); for having PHP generated variables in your CSS.

Comment: I would call that a work around rather than an answer. There are reasons it is the way it is beyond the luxury of syntax highlighting.